# Prove that $\inf(1,2) =1$

Tags: real-analysis

Could somebody verify my thinking on this?
Let $S=(1,2)$, then 1 is the lower bound of $S$.
Need to show that 1 is the greatest lower bound of $S$.

Proof by contradiction: Assume $\inf{S}=l>1$ is a greater lower bound.

$$Let \,m=l-\Bigl(\frac{1+l}{2}\Bigr)\text{ then, } \\
l-\Bigl(\frac{1+l}{2}\Bigr) \leq 1 \\
2l -(1+l) \leq 2 \; (\times2)\\
l-1 \leq 2 \Rightarrow l>1 \text{ (since } l>1 \text{ ) }
 \Rightarrow m>1$$

$l$ is therefore not the infimum of $S$ and $\inf{S}=1$

Comment: Where do you get the inequality $l-\Bigl(\frac{1+l}{2}\Bigr) \leq 1$ from? In fact for $l>3$ this is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to show that

$l - \frac {l-1}{2} < l$ and  $l - \frac {l-1}{2} \in S$

Thus $l$ cannot be the lower bound of S.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is unclear and contains multiple errors:

1. It is not true that $l>1$ implies  $$l-\Bigl(\frac{1+l}{2}\Bigr)
       \leq 1.$$ The inequality is equivalent to $l\leq3$, so you could
   first argue that $l\leq3$.
2. Also, you conclude with the line $$l-1\leq2\quad\Rightarrow\quad
   l>1\quad\Rightarrow\quad m>1.$$ The first implication is true
   because $l>1$ by assumption, but this also makes it a rather void
   implication. Note that the implication is false for general
   $l\in\Bbb{R}$. The second implication is false; for $l=2$ you have
   $m=\tfrac12$.
3. You finish by stating that $$\text{"$l$ is therefore not the infimum
   of $S$..."},$$ but I have no idea how this should follow from the
   preceding statements.

I would suggest that you prove that no number $l>1$ can be a lower bound of $S$ by exhibiting a number $m\in S$ such that $m<l$. Of course $m$ will depend on $l$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $b = inf(S)$ 
Case: $1<b<2$. Then

choose $a=(1+b)/2$ and so $a<b$ and $a \in S$.

Case: $2≤b$. Then

choose $a=(1+2)/2$ and once again $a<b$ and $a \in S$.

Therefore

$inf(S)=1$

Comment: I'm not sure the reason for second case?

Comment: @alortimor what's that you don't understand? $2 \le b $ and  $a = 3/2$ then $a<b$ and $3/2 \in S$. Therefore $b$ can not be greater than 2

Comment: Check [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proofs-regarding-the-supremum-or-infimum-of-a-bounded-set#toc2) out for more

Answer (score 0):

The infimum of a set is the greatest lower bound. Denote $\beta:=\inf\{x:x\in(1,2)\}$. As $1$ is a lower bound of $(1,2)$, we infer $\beta \geq 1$. Assume $\beta >1$.

Take a strictly decreasing sequence $x_{n}\subset (1,2)$ such that $\lim_{n}x_{n}=1$. Then there exists $n_{0}$ such that $x_{n}< \beta$ for every $n\geq n_{0}$, which is contradictory with the fact that $\beta $ is a lower bound of $(1,2)$.